# MySql update query not working-generic error

Tags: mysql

I get a generic error message, and have no idea what the problem is with the query. What do I do to fix this?

Query explanation: there are two tables, Invoice, and temp. I need to take zip codes from temp table and push them to the Invoice table, based on the invoice number.

```
START TRANSACTION

UPDATE 
Invoice
SET 
Invoice.zip_code = (SELECT zip_code FROM temp WHERE temp.invoice_number = Invoice.invoice_number)
WHERE 
Invoice.invoice_date >= '2017-08-01'

ROLLBACK
```

this is the error:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'UPDATE  Invoice SET  Invoice.zip_code = (SELECT
>   zip_code FROM temp WHERE temp' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add semicolon after each command.

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE 
Invoice
SET 
Invoice.zip_code = (SELECT zip_code FROM temp WHERE temp.invoice_number = Invoice.invoice_number)
WHERE 
Invoice.invoice_date >= '2017-08-01';

ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like @Daniel Blais is right. One thing you can do to troubleshoot is to break the query down and run each part individually. That will help you find out what's wrong.

`SELECT zip_code FROM temp WHERE temp.invoice_number = Invoice.invoice_number;`

One other question: Why are you rolling back after the table is updated? Don't you want to commit?

Comment: I never used transactions before, I was just testing out how it runs. More importantly I'm trying to figure out how to view query results before I commit or rollback.